# Box2D and Sand in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I want to create a game where you shoot a rocket into the ground (Sand) and it blows, and moves the sand to the sides...
Is it possible in Box2D? breakable little objects?
It's almost pixel perfect collusion detection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but beware your performance is going to be pretty weak. See the following articles (sorry guys, I normally like to paste in code instead of just link but there is are too much of it).

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/01/17/create-real-explosions-with-box2d-adding-textures/
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/01/05/create-real-explosions-with-box2d-exploding-objects-and-setting-the-center-of-explosion-with-mouse-click/
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/12/08/create-real-explosions-with-box2d/

As far as dirt flying out when the ground breaks, the dirt doesn't have to be physical, you can just fake that with some particle effects. (Lots of tutorials on those things [here](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=151))

Answer (score 0):

In box2d it's not possible to break an object other than to remove the old one and create many new objects. If you need `almost pixel perfect collision detection` you'd need lots of objects. A `100x100` square contains `10 000` pixels.

A year ago I created a physical simulation involving many small particle-like objects using box2d. You can find the video [here](http://vimeo.com/17840705). The number of objects you see there is close to maximum `Alchemy version of box2d` could handle. AS3 version failed with much less.

You should google how it was done in old-school games like Scorched Earth for example. Or it might be possible to "cut" sand particles in area of effect of your missile from box2d shape, create many small particles, simulate them and join back to main terrain shape. But it sound very complicated.